# How can I handle InputScope="Number" data ( XAML)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, inputscope

I 've created 3 text box with input scope = "number " one for the day , one for the mounth and one for the year - I want to nd also verify that the input is corect , how can i do this ? Iimagine from c#...

Answer (score 0):

first you can refer to the code of Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit 's DatePick

second if you just want to handle this in a easy way, + event of textChanged

and check your textbox 's value